# Why am I getting a segmentation fault error on my merge sort program

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, segmentation-fault

My program used to work until I decided to change my arrays to vectors, now it keeps producing a segmentation fault instead of outputting the sorted vector and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void Merge(vector<int> numbers, int i, int j, int k) {
   int mergedSize;                            
   int mergePos;                              
   int leftPos;                              
   int rightPos;                              
  

   mergePos = 0;
   mergedSize = k - i + 1;
   leftPos = i;                           
   rightPos = j + 1; 
                     
   vector<int> mergedNumbers;     
                                             
   
  
   while (leftPos <= j && rightPos <= k) {
      if (numbers[leftPos] < numbers[rightPos]) {
         mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[leftPos];
         ++i;
      }
      else {
         mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[rightPos];
         rightPos;
         
      }
      ++mergePos;
   }
   
 
   while (leftPos <= j) {
      mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[leftPos];
      ++leftPos;
      ++mergePos;
   }
   
  
   while (rightPos <= k) {
      mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[rightPos];
      ++rightPos;
      ++mergePos;
   }
   

   for (mergePos = 0; mergePos < mergedSize; ++mergePos) {
      numbers[i + mergePos] = mergedNumbers[mergePos];
   }
}
void MergeSort(vector<int> numbers, int i, int k) {
   int j;
   
   if (i < k) {
      j = (i + k) / 2;  
      

      MergeSort(numbers, i, j);
      MergeSort(numbers, j + 1, k);
      
      
      Merge(numbers, i, j, k);
   }
}

int main() {
   vector<int> numbers;
   numbers.push_back(10);
    numbers.push_back(2);
     numbers.push_back(78);
      numbers.push_back(4);
       numbers.push_back(45);
        numbers.push_back(32);
         numbers.push_back(7);
          numbers.push_back(11);
   const int NUMBERS_SIZE = 8;
   int i;
   
   cout << "UNSORTED: ";
   for(i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i) {
      cout << numbers[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
   
   MergeSort(numbers, 0, NUMBERS_SIZE - 1);
   
   cout << "SORTED: ";
   for(i = 0; i < NUMBERS_SIZE; ++i) {
      cout << numbers[i] << " "; 
   }
   cout << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

I am new to programming and this most likely is a dumb mistake on my part but I would love to understand why this is happening.

Comment: You never resize `mergedNumbers` before assigning to it. So things like `mergedNumbers[mergePos] = ` will be writing out of bounds

Comment: If there's a segmentation fault, you can stop at this point in your debugger (or load the core file, on *NIX). Then you'd know exactly what was happening when it occurred. This might allow you to figure out the problem yourself, and if not, you'd have some information to add to your question. Why would I read all your code to try and guess where it crashed, when you could have just told us?

Comment: I voted to close as "Typo"(s)

Answer (score 1):

Your vector has a size of zero. Change

```
vector<int> mergedNumbers;
```

to

```
vector<int> mergedNumbers(mergedSize);
```

Or alternatively use `push_back` when you add items to your vector.

Just like arrays, vectors don't resize themselves automatically. You have to use methods like `push_back` or `resize` if you want to change the size of a vector.

You have another problem with your code. You are passing the vector by value, which means you are sorting a copy of your vector, the original vector in `main` will be unchanged. Use a reference instead.

```
void Merge(vector<int>& numbers, int i, int j, int k) {
```

and

```
void MergeSort(vector<int>& numbers, int i, int k) {
```

**EDIT**

Also two errors which look like typos

```
 if (numbers[leftPos] < numbers[rightPos]) {
     mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[leftPos];
     ++i;
  }
  else {
     mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[rightPos];
     rightPos;
     
  }
```

should be

```
 if (numbers[leftPos] < numbers[rightPos]) {
     mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[leftPos];
     ++leftPos;                // <-- here
  }
  else {
     mergedNumbers[mergePos] = numbers[rightPos];
     ++rightPos;               // <-- here  
  }
```

Comment: I did that and the segmentation fault is still there.